# Nested ExpandableListView Only Works Every Other Child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a system of nested ExpandableListViews that continue on for a few generations (a tree-type layout) for comments. Each top-level comment can have comments with children on those comments. To do so, I have a main ExpandableListView to store all the top level comments, and each "comment" XML contains an ExpandableListView for any child comments. The adapter for my ExpandableListView is as follows

```
public class ExpandableCommentAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private static final class ViewHolder {
        TextView textLabel;
    }

    private final List<CommentNode> itemList;
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context main;

    public ExpandableCommentAdapter(Context context, List<CommentNode> itemList) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.itemList = itemList;
        main = context;


    }

    @Override
    public CommentNode getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

        CommentNode n = itemList.get(groupPosition);
        ArrayList<CommentNode> comments = new ArrayList<CommentNode>();
        for (CommentNode node : n.walkTree(TraversalMethod.BREADTH_FIRST)) {
            if (node.getParent().getComment().getId() == n.getComment().getId()) {
                comments.add(node);
            }

        }
        Log.v("RedditSlide", "COMMENT CHILD SIZE:" + comments.size());
        return comments.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        CommentNode n = itemList.get(groupPosition);
        ArrayList<CommentNode> comments = new ArrayList<CommentNode>();
        CommentNode comment = n;
        for (CommentNode node : comment.walkTree(TraversalMethod.BREADTH_FIRST)) {
            if (node.getParent().getComment().getId() == comment.getComment().getId()) {
                comments.add(node);
            }

        }
        return comments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
                             final ViewGroup parent) {

        final CommentNode user = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment, parent, false);
        }
        TextView author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        TextView comm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentLine);
        TextView upvote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.upvotePost);

        author.setText(user.getComment().getAuthor());
        comm.setText(user.getComment().getBody());
        upvote.setText(user.getComment().getScore() + "");


        ArrayList<CommentNode> comments = new ArrayList<CommentNode>();
        CommentNode comment = user;
        for (CommentNode node : comment.walkTree(TraversalMethod.BREADTH_FIRST)) {
            if (node.getParent().getComment().getId() == comment.getComment().getId()) {
                comments.add(node);
            }

        }

        ExpandableCommentAdapter adapter = new ExpandableCommentAdapter(convertView.getContext(), comments);
        ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentsListUnder);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public CommentNode getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return itemList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(final int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final CommentNode user = itemList.get(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment, parent, false);
        }
        TextView author = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
        TextView comm = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.commentLine);
        TextView upvote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.upvotePost);

        author.setText(user.getComment().getAuthor());
        comm.setText(user.getComment().getBody());
        upvote.setText(user.getComment().getScore() + "");

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

My Comment XML is as follows

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"

    android:background="#ff2b2b2b"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ccrama"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/commentLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="COMMENT"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/upvote"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:onClick="upvote"
            android:padding="5dp"

            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/iconupvote"

            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/downvote"
            android:layout_width="20dp"

            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"

            android:onClick="downvote"

            android:padding="5dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/icondownvote"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upvotePost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:text="30"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/commentsListUnder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
        android:background="#ff2b2b2b"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The issue I'm having is the "expandableness" of the child comments seems to skip a generation. Level 1, Level 3, etc all have expansion and their children are visible, but Level 2 can't expand, and only one child is visible. Further children (4, 5, 6...) aren't visible, and Level 3 *has* an expanding icon but when tapped shows no children.

What am I doing wrong with my layout/system?
Thanks!

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/shahbazhashmi/nested-expandable-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are two things.  One you are attempting to nest scrollable views that scroll in the same direction.  Android can not handle this situation correctly and you will get all sorts of crazy behavior. Attempting to "hack" around the issues will just cause all sorts of headaches.

The second issues is that you are embedding adapters within adapters.  While this "could" work, it is really not recommended.  There is no guarantee to how many times a `getChildView` or `getParentView` will be called for the same position number.  Sometimes it's once.  Sometimes it's twice.  Heck it could be 4 times.  Each time you'd be recreating a new adapter that in-turn will invoke it's `getChildView` or `getParentView` methods multiple times per position. To put simply, it's a major performance concern.

Your best solution is to rework a UX design that does not entail embedding `ExpandableListViews` and adapters.

Comment: Yeah I see the issue with my method. What would you do in my case?

Comment: Its tough.  If you toss aside the expand-ability part, then you can just render everything at once with a normal list view.  Or only allow one level of collapsing and just show all sub comments as part of a child item.  Otherwise, if you want to show expanding and collapsing of sub comments you'll need to sorta do a trick.  Whereby, selecting a child item actually loads in the sub comments as new data...as if you expanded the childview.  You'll need to track then whether a child item is a comment with more child items or not in order to pull of this trick.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean. I was thinking of possibly loading every comment at once and then adding a margin to the left side to indent for every level down it is (level 2 20dp, level 3 30dp, etc). The only issue with that method is expand ability, which might be harder to implement. For that, though, I could possibly make a method to get the ids of the children comments (every comment has a specific id) and hide the comments of that ID from the ListView, which I might end up doing. As long as the user sees they are nested I can live with the fact that they really aren't.